# Overrides or depreciated issue in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I get this warning while building the apk.
How do I resolve it?

```
Note: C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-1.0.3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a 
deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_facebook_login-3.0.0\android\src\main\java\com\roughike\facebooklogin\facebooklogin\FacebookLoginPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-1.1.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\auth\FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin.java uses or overrides a 
deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

Plugin Versions

```
firebase_auth: ^1.1.0
firebase_core :
flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
```

Comment: Have you updated `Gradle` version ?

Comment: How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have read the same problem and I found the solution [here](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1401) on GitHub.

First, get the latest versions of your dependencies from [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/).

Then run these 3 commands in the terminal:

```
$ flutter pub upgrade

$ flutter pub get

$ flutter clean
```

And then run your project

```
$ flutter run
```

This will hopefully help you.

Answer (score 1):

I have solve this issue by using this command

```
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```

After this you will find some errors to fix up. If you're done with this. Hope project will run well