# notes will affect when Generate flutter app bundles?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, bundle

when i try to build flutter App Bundle in android studio (RUN -- Build -- Build App Bundle)  i get the following Notes:

```
C:\Src\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color build appbundle

Building without sound null safety
For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety

Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                          

Note: C:\Src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-1.1.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Note: C:\Src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_share-2.0.0\android\src\main\java\com\example\fluttershare\FlutterSharePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Note: C:\Src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_analytics-8.0.2\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseanalytics\FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_analytics-8.0.2\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseanalytics\FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\Src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-1.1.2\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\auth\FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.


Note: C:\Src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-1.0.7\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\FlutterFirebaseFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-1.0.7\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\streamhandler\TransactionStreamHandler.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Removed unused resources: Binary resource data reduced from 149KB to 149KB: Removed 0%
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                            368,5s
√ Built build\app\outputs\bundle\release\app-release.aab (28.6MB).
Process finished with exit code 0
```

But in the end the application comes out as normal without errors (as shown by the previous code)
these errors will affect when publishing the application in Google Play and download and used by users?

my pubspec.yaml file :

```
name:flutter_app
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons:
  flutter_svg:
  google_fonts:
  json_annotation:
  font_awesome_flutter:
  url_launcher:

  firebase_core:
  firebase_analytics:
  firebase_auth:
  cloud_firestore:

  flutter_share:

  path_provider:
  http:
  provider:
  google_mobile_ads:

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner:
  json_serializable:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/icons/
    - assets/images/
    - assets/data/
  fonts:
    - family: ElMessiri
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/ElMessiri-Bold.ttf
        - asset: fonts/ElMessiri-Medium.ttf
        - asset: fonts/ElMessiri-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/ElMessiri-SemiBold.ttf
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a solution:
[Overrides or depreciated issue in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67125779/overrides-or-depreciated-issue-in-flutter)

Which FLutter chanel are you on? I've been getting these errors ever since I started using Firebase on the stable build channel. Since it affects neither my debug nor my release builds, I've made the assumption that this deprecation issue will be fixed by the time the stable channel makes its way into the master channel.

Answer (score 0):

Just
Go into File → Invalidate Caches / Restart
[image]